# How to recursively display the elements of a list?

Tags: java, recursion

I have got this so for which will do it successfully but it will also print the empty list message but I'm not too sure why? I'm still learning about recursion so apologises if I have missed something simple.

```
public void recursiveDisplayElements(MyList<Integer> m) {

    // -----------------------------
    // I. SCENARIO IDENTIFICATION
    // -----------------------------
    int scenario = 0;

    if (m.length() == 0) {

        scenario = 1;
    } else {

        scenario = 2;
    }
    // -----------------------------
    // II. SCENARIO IMPLEMENTATION
    // -----------------------------

    switch (scenario) {

    case 1:

        System.out.println("MyList is empty!");
        break;

    case 2:

        int e0 = m.getElement(0);
        m.removeElement(0);
        System.out.print(e0);
        recursiveDisplayElements(m);
        m.addElement(0, e0);

    }

}
```

Comment: It's printing the empty list message too because at the end there are 0 items left in your list. Your break condition is the same as if you tried listing an empty directory. So you'd want to probably pass in an additional parameter in case 2 like `recursiveDisplayElements(m, true)` to determine if it's actually being called recursively or not. Make the default for the second parameter `false`, so then you can check if this is the first execution (in which case output "list empty") or if it's from recursion (and don't output "list empty").

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you sir!

Comment: just to clarify, then the first time you'd run this like `recursiveDisplayElements(m)` and then in case 2 of that function you'd call `recursiveDisplayElements(m, true)`. And then finally in case 1 you'd check that second parameter and if it's `!= true` then you'd output "list empty" because it wasn't called recursively. Otherwise, if it's `== true` then it was called recursively and you know this is your break condition (and you don't need to output that message).

Comment: Thanks again I understand the problem and solution you are suggesting but I can only use one method as its for a college project with set methods we are to implement so I just have to figure out a different way of doing it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you can only use one method, perhaps you can implement it without removing from the list and passing in an index as well.  `public void recursiveDisplayElements(MyList<Integer> m, int index)`  to kick things off you would call with your list and 0 as index.  If index==0 && m.size() == 0, you can display `System.out.println("MyList is empty!");`  otherwise you could print `m.getElement(index)` and then call `recursiveDisplayElements(m, index++);` until `index == m.size()-1)`

Comment: That would be they way all right, thank you. Having said that I am not aloud to alter the original template of the method in any way. To do this I have decided to simply remove MyList is empty message and add "System.out.println(); break;"

Answer (score 1):

in this recursive function, each time the list is not empty, the function will remove one element from it and print it.
It will continue to do so until the list is totally emptied and go in the case 1 where it will write that the list is empty.

In a recursive function the case number 1 is the stop case wich will always be executed at the end.

Sorry if my explication isn't clear.